# Is it possible to use template with composite component in JSF 2?

Tags: templates, jsf-2, composite-component

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    ...
    template="inputLayout.xhtml">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="name" />
        <composite:attribute name="value" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
      <!-- <ui:define name="content"> -->
          <h:message for="textPanel" style="color:red;" />
          #{cc.attrs.name} : 
          <h:inputText id="name" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
      <!-- <ui:define> -->
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

The problem is that even the **ui:define** is commented the content is rendered.
So it is like the **ui:define** is ignored or Am I missing some thing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will indeed not work. You need [`<ui:decorate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/decorate.html) inside the implementation instead.

```
<ui:component
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
    <cc:interface>
        ...
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/inputLayout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                ...
            </ui:define>
        </ui:decorate>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```