# What is the real conceptual difference between ui:decorate and ui:include?

Tags: jsf, facelets

It occurs ago me that `ui:decorate` is functionally the same as `ui:include` except that you can also pass `ui:param` and `ui:define` to the included file.

Am I crazy?

**EDIT :** Although in fact you can pass `ui:param` to a `ui:include` file too, it turns out I am already doing it. Maybe you can pass a `ui:define` as well, I will check and edit here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concrete problem. So I'd say, yes you're crazy :)

Comment: @BalusC I may indeed be crazy, but I'm not stating a concrete problem, just a general principle. I've been trying to figure out what actual difference exists between these two constructs and I can't find any. Possibly ui:include doesn't support ui:define, I've been having other problems while testing that.

Comment: Ah you're just asking for the conceptual difference?

Comment: @BalusC If there is one ;-) I understand that ui:decorate is conceptually 'for' templates rather than include files but in terms of implementation it seems to me to be exactly the same thing.

Comment: The `ui:include` doesn't have the template overhead and is therefore theoretically more efficient if all you need is "just" an include.

Comment: @BalusC What template overhead? ui:include understands ui:param so it does at least have some of it.

Comment: The `<ui:param>` just set an alias in the EL scope. Not much to do with templating.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The main difference between [`<ui:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html) and [`<ui:decorate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/decorate.html) is that the `<ui:decorate>` is intended to allow insertion of user-defined template components, while the `<ui:include>` is intended to include an existing and already-predefined template.

This indeed means that the `<ui:decorate>` supports [`<ui:define>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) for user-defined template components in its body and can insert it at the [`<ui:insert>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/insert.html) place inside the template.

Here's a -somewhat clumsy- example to show where it can be used:

`/WEB-INF/templates/field.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:outputLabel for="#{id}" value="#{label}" />
    <ui:insert name="input" />
    <h:message id="#{id}_message" for="#{id}" />
</ui:composition>
```

`/page.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/field.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="label" value="Foo" />
        <ui:param name="id" value="foo" />
        <ui:define name="input">
            <h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
    <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/field.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="label" value="Bar" />
        <ui:param name="id" value="bar" />
        <ui:define name="input">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" required="true" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

Note that it renders the components nicely in each cell of the panel grid. Again, this particular example is pretty clumsy, I'd just have used a [tag file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component) instead. Only if it was a larger section, e.g. a whole form whose e.g. its header or footer should be customizable, then an `<ui:decorate>` would have been appropriate.

Another major advantage of `<ui:decorate>` is that it allows you to use a composite component with a template. See also [Is it possible to use template with composite component in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817851/is-it-possible-to-use-template-with-composite-component-in-jsf-2)

Comment: I don't understand the difference between 'user-defined template components' and 'existing  and pre-defined template'.

Comment: In the given `/page.xhtml` example, the `<ui:define>` is where the enduser can define variable template components.

Comment: I understand that part, I just don't understand the distinction you are drawing.

Comment: It isn't possible to change the page fragment which is included by `<ui:include>` using `<ui:insert>`/`<ui:define>`.

Comment: @BalusC that shed some light - what about <ui:composition template="./someTemplate.xhtml"> - it seems to not behave the same like ui:include and ui:decorate - what is the trick about this one?

Comment: @Toskan: The `<ui:composition>` ignores anything outside the tag. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504190/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-jsf-page-without-building-the-whole-project/10504830#10504830