# JSF/Primefaces: ui:insert in ui:include

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, insert, include

I want to use ui:insert/ui:define to replace some content in a template file. Inside the template file there is an include of another file and inside this file is the ui:insert

The ui:define is not working in this case. If however the code of the footer.xhtml file is included in the template.xhtml the ui:define is working fine.

Is it not possible to use ui:insert/ui:define inside an ui:include?

**template.xhtml:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
      xmlns:debug="http://XYZ/jsf/debug"
      xmlns:util="http://XYZ/ibk/util"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body >

        <f:view>
            <div id="headerWrapper">
                <!-- META-NAVIGATION -->
                <div id="metanavWrapper"  >
                    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix pagewidth" >
                        <ui:include src="metanav.xhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="contentWrapper" >
                <!--div id="content" class="pagewidth"-->
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="contentMenuLeft">
                        <ui:include src="navigationMenu.xhtml" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="contentDisplay">
                        <ui:insert name="content" />
                        <ui:insert name="help" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <util:footer />

        </f:view>

        <ui:insert name="dialog"/>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

--

```
<util:footer />
```

could also be written as ui:include, results in the same...

**footer.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                >

   <div id="footerWrapper">
      <f:subview id="footerWrapper">


         <h:panelGroup id="footer" >
            <div >

               <ui:insert name="replace" />

            </div>
         </h:panelGroup>
      </f:subview>


   </div>



</ui:composition>
```

**another.xhtml: (snippet)**

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="replace">         
    <h:panelGroup>
       <div>
          <p:outputLabel value="test"/>
       </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to include the footer.xhtml in the template.xhtml by

```
<ui:decorate template="footer.xhtml" />
```

Then the insert/define is working!

More info here: [What is the real conceptual difference between ui:decorate and ui:include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778068/what-is-the-real-conceptual-difference-between-uidecorate-and-uiinclude)

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, your `<ui:define name="replace">`will never work without the footer, because the corresponding `<ui:insert name="replace" />` is inside of it and only exists when the footer is included. No insert, no define.

When you call your another.xhtml (or any other site with `template="..."` ), the compiler will assemble all `include`s first and then add all all `define`ed code at the places of the corresponding `insert`-tags.

Comment: I that would be true, the code above should work, because footer.xhtml is included in template.xhtml
So either the process is the other way around (isert/define before include), or there is an error in the code...

Comment: have you tried the real `<ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />`- include?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Is not working, either. Is that working for you? Then I would probably have an error in my code.

Comment: It is working in my project. 
I have a project-specific template.xhtml that has an underlayed base-template. Inside template.xhtml, the parameter application is defined. The ui:insert for "application" is nested in a extra xhtml that is included in the base-template.

Perhaps try :
    <ui:insert name="footer">
        <ui:include src="footer.html" />
    </ui:insert>

Comment: Wrapping the insert in an include doesn't help. Can you/someone probably post your/their working code?