# Put start and end tags in separate include files

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, uiinclude

I want to include html codes from different files into my `main.xhtml` page. But this doesn't work with the `<ui:include>`. Because the codes are separated to different files and this makes that each file has invalid html codes.

What I mean:

`html1.html`

```
<div>
```

`html2.html`

```
</div>
```

`main.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

INCLUDE HTML1

<h:outputLabel value="blablabla" />

INCLUDE HTML2

</ui:composition>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why would you want to create invalid XHTML files?

Comment: @mplungjan, actually the extension of html1 and html2 doesn't matter . I've edited my post and made them as html;)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense. You're not allowed to have syntactically invalid XML in an individual Facelet file. Moreover, you can't include plain vanilla HTML via `<ui:include>` or whatever `<ui:xxx>` tag. Those have to be real Facelet compositions (and thus be syntactically valid XML).

I gather that you'd like to control the body of an include template. In that case, put them together in a single template file with an `<ui:insert>` representing the place where you'd like to insert the body:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <div>
        <ui:insert/>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Then, use `<ui:decorate>` on it:

```
<ui:decorate template="html.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="blablabla" />
</ui:decorate>
```

[Note that `<h:outputLabel>` serves an entirely different purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute).

#### See also:

- [What is the real conceptual difference between ui:decorate and ui:include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778068/what-is-the-real-conceptual-difference-between-uidecorate-and-uiinclude)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Answer (score 1):

Divide your code into more files like this:

```
include file1_before_div
<div>
include file1_after_div
<h:outputLabel value="blablabla" />
include file2_before_div_close
</div>
include file2_after_div_close
```