# ui:insert inside ui:include is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, jsf-1.2, uiinclude

Is it possible to write `<ui:insert>` inside `<ui:include>`? When I am trying to use `<ui:define name="jsInclude">` the content is not visible. When trying this with JSF 1.2, this is working but not with JSF 2.2.

Can anyone help me in understanding what am I missing with the templates concept in JSF 2.2?

Thanks!!

Below is my code

This is the template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <head>
        <title><ui:insert name="browserTitle">My Page</ui:insert></title>
        <ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert>
        <ui:include src="myIncludeFile.xhtml" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <!-- START OF BODY CONTENT //-->
            <ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
            <!-- END OF BODY CONTENT //-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the included file

```
<span xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition>
        <ui:insert name="jsInclude"></ui:insert>
    </ui:composition>
</span>
```

Below is the main client page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html 
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition template="../templates/myTemplate.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="browserTitle">My Page</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="head">
            This is head
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="jsInclude">
            This is js include!
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="body">
            This is body!
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: You need `<ui:include>` inside `<ui:insert>` such as `<ui:insert name="head"><ui:include src="myIncludeFile.xhtml" /></ui:insert>`. Those template pages should be placed under the `WEB-INF` directory so that they are not served to clients, if they demand template pages using the corresponding URL.

Comment: Try to change included file to `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<ui:component> ... </ui:component>
</html>`

Comment: I faced the same issue, I was trying to extract a header which contains lot of primefaces controls into a separate file to be more readible. I tried the 2 solutions above and both didn't work. I'll post a solution if I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ui:decorate` instead of `ui:insert`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778068/what-is-the-real-conceptual-difference-between-uidecorate-and-uiinclude).