# Facelets multi-level templates - ui:define not rendered

Tags: jsf, facelets, myfaces

I have 2 basic templates - one with a side menu, and one without - that both ui:include a common page which contains ui:insert tags (templates are largish, so basic example below).

Using Mojarra everything worked ok, but now I have migrated to MyFaces the ui:insert tags are ignored and the content of the related ui:define does not get rendered (i.e. 'Here are my results' is not displayed).

Should I be specifying included-page.xhtml as a template somehow? I tried

```
<ui:composition template="included-page.xhtml" />
```

instead of

```
<ui:include src="included-page.xhtml" />
```

but lost the CSS.

Hoping someone can suggest a solution :)

Many thanks,

Neil

my-page.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/templates/default-template.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="title" value="My Title" />

    <ui:define name="results">

        Here are my results

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

default-template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>#{title}</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <ui:include src="included-page.xhtml" />

</h:body>

</html>
```

included-page.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:insert name="results">

    </ui:insert>

</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ui:include>` should have been an `<ui:decorate>`.

```
<ui:decorate template="included-page.xhtml" />
```

But if the `included-page.xhtml` is by itself not reused elsewhere, I wonder why it isn't just been inlined in the master template instead.

#### See also:

- [Difference between ui:composition and ui:decorate in Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091927/difference-between-uicomposition-and-uidecorate-in-facelets/13092844#13092844)
- [What is the real conceptual difference between ui:decorate and ui:include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778068/what-is-the-real-conceptual-difference-between-uidecorate-and-uiinclude/10790780#10790780)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC - not surprisingly it now works :). The 'real' included-page.xhtml is currently used by 2 different templates.