# Using additional components as a parameter to `<ui:include>`

Tags: jsf-2

When writing various components (specifically in this case a pop-up), there are cases where you need more customization than a `<ui:param>` can provide. Specifically, I'd like to be able to `<ui:define>` a section for a `<ui:include>`, or otherwise have the default, something like:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<div class="overlay pop-up">
    <aside class="pop-up">
        <main>
            <h2>
                ${headerText}
            </h2>

            <p>${contentText}</p>
        </main>
        <div class="buttons-holder">
            <ui:insert name="button-content">
                <button class="ok">OK</button>
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
</ui:composition>
```

Where you would use it as

```
    <ui:include src="pop-up-ok.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="headerText" value="Please try again."/>
        <ui:param name="contentText" value="The QR code could not be scanned - please try again."/>

        <ui:define name="button-content">
            <button>Different button</button>
            <button>Another button</button>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:include>
```

`<ui:define>`/`<ui:define>` appears to only be supported in templates however - is there any equivalent that would provide for what I'm trying to do? Or would I have to write a full Java-based custom component?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13180043

Comment: @BalusC That helps perfectly :) Should I just delete this question? Or leave it as a pointer?

Comment: Just leave it as feed for search engines.