# Inner content composite component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have my composite component `<my:panel/>` :

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="header" />
  <composite:attribute name="content" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">#{cc.attrs.header}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      #{cc.attrs.content}
    </div>
  </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

And i used:

```
<my:panel header="My header" content="My content"  />
```

Well, now i want to add html (a html table e.g.) code in content attribute.
How could i do for `<my:tag/>` works like this?

```
<my:tag header="My header" >
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</my:tag>
```

Comment: You might want to look at ui:decorate and these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778068/what-is-the-real-conceptual-difference-between-uidecorate-and-uiinclude
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817851/is-it-possible-to-use-template-with-composite-component-in-jsf-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<composite:insertChildren/>`?

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="header" />
  <composite:attribute name="content" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">#{cc.attrs.header}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      #{cc.attrs.content}
    </div>
  </div>
  <composite:insertChildren/>
</composite:implementation>
```